# INNER JOINING THE TABLE ITSELF GIVES No column name was specified for column 2

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
    construction AS T2
    INNER JOIN  
    (
      SELECT   project,MAX(report_date)
       FROM construction 
            GROUP BY project
     ) AS R 

     ON T2.project=R.project AND T2.report_date=R.report_date
```

getting this error. plz help
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'R'

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The problem is probablly, the **max(report_date)** change it to **max(report_dare) as report_date** than it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add alias for `MAX(report_date)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM construction AS T2
INNER JOIN  
(
  SELECT project,MAX(report_date) AS report_date
  FROM construction 
  GROUP BY project
) AS R 
  ON T2.project     = R.project 
 AND T2.report_date = R.report_date;
```

In `SQL Server` you can use syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM construction AS T2
INNER JOIN  
(
  SELECT project,MAX(report_date)
  FROM construction 
  GROUP BY project
) AS R(project, report_date)
  ON T2.project     = R.project 
 AND T2.report_date = R.report_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specific the `MAX(report_date)` with an alias `report_date`.
Because your table R have two columns `project,MAX(report_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not specified column name for inner query

You have to write your query as

SELECT *
FROM construction 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT project,MAX(report_date)"Max_ReportDate"
  FROM construction 
  GROUP BY project
) Max_construction 
  ON construction.project     = Max_construction .project 
 AND construction.report_date = Max_construction .Max_ReportDate